# Session working only one time and this one time creating session nuxt3

Tags: express, session, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

session working only one time and after second session i cant get session again, i tried with credentials: true and use headers cookie and they dont work.

Js framework: nuxt.js
Backend: express.js

There code of response:

```
//Creating session
const response = await axios.get(`http://100.104.233.94:4040/api/login/callback?code=${this.code}`, { credentials: 'include' });
//getting session, returns {session: null}
const session = await axios.get(`http://100.104.233.94:4040/api/get/session`, { credentials: 'include' });
```

i tried a lib h3 and nuxt auth but all didn't help